# Reactjs - retrieve attributes from event.target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, key

I have a component which renders `Input type='select'`: (I am using reactstrap)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Input,
    Button,
    Col,
} from 'reactstrap'
import {
    withRouter,
} from 'react-router'
import Context from '../../../../../provider'

class NewPost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            subreddits: [],
            subreddit_selected: '',
            subreddit_id: 0,
            ...
        }
        this.handleSubredditSelect = this.handleSubredditSelect.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/reddit/r/')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                subreddits: json,
                ...
            })
        })
    }

    handleSubredditSelect(event) {
        console.log('selected id: ',event.target.id)
        this.setState({
            subreddit_selected: event.target.value,
            subreddit_id: event.target.id,
        }, () => 
            this.props.history.push(`/${this.state.subreddit_selected}/new/`)
        )
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Consumer>
                {context => {
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <Form
                                ...
                            >
                                <FormGroup row>
                                    <Col sm={7}>
                                        <Input 
                                            type="select"
                                            onChange={this.handleSubredditSelect}
                                            required
                                        > 
                                            <option key='0' disabled selected>Select an Option</option>
                                            {this.state.subreddits.map((subreddit) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <option key={subreddit.id} id={subreddit.id}>{'r/' + subreddit.name}</option>
                                                )
                                            })}
                                        </Input>
                                    </Col>
                                </FormGroup>
                                ...
                        </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    }}
                </Context.Consumer>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(NewPost)
```

So, I have a function `handleSubredditSelect` which does the following:

```
handleSubredditSelect(event) {  
    this.setState({
        subreddit_selected: event.target.value,
        subreddit_id: event.target.id,
    }, () => 
        this.props.history.push(`/${this.state.subreddit_selected}/new/`)
    )
}
```

In this function I am not getting any value for `event.target.id`.

I have tried `event.target.key` as well but that returned an empty string "".

I want to set `subreddit_id` in **state** to the selected option's **ID**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selecting does not work because `event.target` in `<select>` element returns entire tree with options:

```
// result of event.target:
<select>
  <option id="id-1" value="some1">some1</option>
  <option id="id-2" value="some2">some2</option>
  <option id="id-3" value="some3">some3</option>
</select>
```

Instead the selected one.

---

For accessing the current option element from `select` you should rely on `selectedIndex`:

```
event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].id
```

---

The code:

```
export default class SelectForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "some1",
      id: "id-1"
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    console.log("event", event.target, event.target.selectedIndex);

    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
      id: event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].id
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select value={this.state.sex} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option id="id-1" value="some1">some1</option>
          <option id="id-2" value="some2">some2</option>
          <option id="id-3" value="some3">some3</option>
        </select>
        ID: {this.state.id}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit 9l814zo9yr]

Comment: Ya `console.log(event.target)` returns the whole `select`. So, how to solve that. If I am not wrong, the code that you put also faces the same problem!

Comment: @SreekarMouli Yes, sorry but I was still coding on it in meantime, please check it now, it should be working :) use `event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].id `

Comment: So for accessing any other attributes, we just do `event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].attribute`

Answer (score 1):

You can use selectedIndex attribute of select:

```
handleSubredditSelect(event) {  
    const selectedOption = event.target.childNodes[event.target.selectedIndex];
    this.setState({
        subreddit_selected: event.target.value,
        subreddit_id: selectedOption.id,
    }, () => 
        this.props.history.push(`/${this.state.subreddit_selected}/new/`)
    )
}
```

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/n5679m5owj

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK event.target.id should be working, doing the same in my project.

But should't it be

```
<Input 
type="select"
onChange={(e) => this.handleSubredditSelect}
required>`
```

? (No parantheses after the methodname)

Comment: I think it should be either `onChange={this.handleSubredditChange}` or `onChange={(e)=>this.handleSubredditChange(e)}`

Comment: ah yes sorry, messed it up :)